# Cant use a useDispatch inside a useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

So Im receiving the following error when using a useDispatch inside a useEffect

> Line 58:5:  React Hook "useDispatch" cannot be called inside a
> callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or
> a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

I have a component like follows

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { myModules } from '#/redux/modules';

const Component = () => {
 const images = useSelector(getImages)

  useEffect( () =>  {
    useDispatch(myModules.actions.setMaskVisible(true));
  }, [images]);

}
```

setMaskVisible is pretty much

```
export const SET_MASK_VISIBLE = 'caps/SET_MASK_VISIBLE';
const setMaskVisible = payload => {
  return {
    type: SET_MASK_VISIBLE,
    payload
  };
};

export default { setMaskVisible }
```

Im basically trying to change a redux value, when images update. Why desnt it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#use-redux-state-and-actions-in-react-components). You call `useDispatch` to get a function and call *that* function:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { myModules } from '#/redux/modules';

const Component = () => {
 const images = useSelector(getImages)
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect( () =>  {
    dispatch(myModules.actions.setMaskVisible(true));
  }, [images]);

}
```